# Linqpad not populating

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, linqpad

I have added a connection to an Oracle db in Linqpad and testing the connection is succesful.
However, when pressing the plus sign to populate the conntection the plus-sign disappears and the connection is never populated with tables.
How can I troubleshoot the connection?

(After installating the application I got exceptions from Linqpad about System.Globalization.CultureData.GetNFIValues(NumberFormatInfo nfi). I don't see those exception after restart, however).

Comment: Does it help if you right-click the connection and choose 'Refresh'?

Comment: Unfortunately no.